# How can I check if a website is publicly accessible?

Tags: internet, website, web, intranet

While on an intranet, how can I distinguish whether a website is available publicly or not?

I gave a link to someone and then realized that he could not access it because it was on the intranet. Is there some way to know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a site similar to http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ should do the job.

If you mean a way to find if anouther intranet user can see a internet site, then it depends on firewall settings and similar. Thats a much bigger topic.

Answer (score 4):

I usually use a proxy server such as https://www.hidemyass.com/proxy to test the accessibility of an internally hosted site.

That will access the url on the intranet from a site outside. If you can browse to it through that, then so can others.